# Proof for $2^x > x$ for $x \in \mathrm{R}$ and $x \ge 0$

Tags: real-analysis, real-numbers

I have proved the statement for $1 \ge x \ge 0$ through contradiction and using the floor function, as the exercise recommends to use. I found a way to prove through calculus, but I wanted to know about proof through real analysis and not calculus.
I hope there aren't any mistakes in the title or in the description.

Comment: `\mathbb R` or `\Bbb R` gives $\Bbb R$

Answer (score 6):

Since $2^x\ge 1$ for $x\ge 0$ the inequality holds for $0<x\le 1$. For $x>1$ we have $2^x>2$ then the inequality holds for $1<x\le 2$. For $x>2$, we have $2^x>4$ then the inequality holds for $2<x\le 4$ and so on.

**Remark**

The inequality holds for negative $x$s as well, since $$x<0<2^x$$

Comment: "For  $x>1$  we have $2^x>2$". That is ok for me. " then the inequality '$2^x > x$' holds for $1<x\leq 2$". Can you explain?

Comment: Sure. This is because $2^x> 2\ge x$ for $x\le 2$.

Answer (score 3):

Let $f(x) = 2^x-x.$ To see $f(x) > 0$ on $[1,\infty),$ note that $f(1) = 1$ and that

$$f'(x) = (\ln 2)2^x-1\ \ge (\ln 2)2-1 = \ln 4 -1 > \ln e -1 =0.$$

Thus $f$ is increasing on $[1,\infty),$ which implies $f>0$ there. I'll leave $f>0$ on $[0,1]$ to you.

Answer (score 3):

The generalized [Bernoulli inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli%27s_inequality) says that $(1+y)^x\ge1+yx$ for real $x\ge1, y\ge -1$.

In particular, with $y=1, 2^x\ge1+x>x $ for real $x\ge1$.